# I am unable to understand the logic behind the code (I've added exact queries as comments in the code)

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

Our local ninja Naruto is learning to make shadow-clones of himself and is facing a dilemma. He
only has a limited amount of energy (e) to spare that he must entirely distribute among all of his
clones. Moreover, each clone requires at least a certain amount of energy to function (m) . Your job is
to count the number of different ways he can create shadow clones.
Example:

e=7;m=2

ans = 4

The following possibilities occur:
Make 1 clone with 7 energy

Make 2 clones with 2, 5 energy

Make 2 clones with 3, 4 energy

Make 3 clones with 2, 2, 3 energy.

Note: <2, 5> is the same as <5, 2>.
Make sure the ways are not counted multiple times because of different ordering.

**Answer**

```
int count(int n, int k){
    if((n<k)||(k<1)) return 0;
    else if ((n==k)||(k==1)) return 1;
    else return count(n-1,k-1)+ count(n-k,k);   // logic behind this?
}

int main()
{
    int e,m;            // e is total energy and m is min energy per clone
    scanf("%d %d", &e, &m);
    int max_clones= e/m;
    int i,ans=0;
    for(i=1;i<=max_clones;i++){
        int available = e - ((m-1)*i);   // why is it (m-1)*i instead of m*i
        ans += count(available, i);
    }
    printf("%d",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? The reason why this code works? The time complexity analysis?

Comment: Why the code works. I've added my exact question as comments in the code

Comment: To be honest, i have absolutely no idea what is going on here. Maybe renaming the variables could help understanding. Anyways ill try to give a different solution and post it

Comment: Where did you encounter this task? Please credit the original source of all copied material.

Comment: Coding questions and queries about code are off-topic here.

Comment: The code does not output any value.You're not counting anything. The code won't tell.

Comment: You found an example of godawful code that doesn’t give you the slightest clue what it does and why it does it. There are two solutions: Go to the author with a big stick and force them to add comments and/or useful variable names. Or write the code yourself. To the original author of the code: Total failure.

Comment: HI all, thanks for your replies and apologies for my late response. It is an old assignment question from one of my senior batches from my college. I was preparing for interviews hence wanted help understanding the logic. Also, this is my first time _asking_ a question here so please be kind! I will be more careful the next time. Thank you!

Comment: Part of the text here appears to have been copy-pasted from another source without attribution: See https://www.scribd.com/document/365511363/Assignment-1-CS-F222, Question 2.  [Copying without attribution](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715).

Answer (score 0):

```
Count (energy, clones, min_energy):
    If enregy < min_energy or clones == 0: return 0
    If energy == min_energy or clones == 1: return 1
    Else:
            cnt = 0
            For every cur_energy from min_energy to energy:
                   cnt += Count(energy - cur_energy, clones - 1, cur_energy)
    Return cnt
```

I am pretty sure the algorithm above works just fine. Notice that i have passed to the recursive call cur_energy to avoid counting the same thing multiple times

The idea here is to "choose" the energy each clone takes

Answer (score 0):

The count routine only produces 1 or 0. The else line you refer to is the sum of all these values calculated by recursion.

The (m-1)*i is a mechanism to reduce the total amount of available energy to be what would remain if you paid for all but 1 unit of the cost of a close. This cause all clones to have an equivalent production cost of 1 unit of energy.

For example: if you paid all but \$1 of a purchase and you still had \$1 or more dollars in your pocket, then you know you could pay for the whole thing. The count() routine assumes clones cost 1 unit so we reduce our total appropriately before using it.

Comment: (Has the question been [well-asked](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)?)